# How to redirect one single webpage to another (client-side)?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, redirection

I often access bibliographical databases from one or several publishers for my work (sciencedirect.com, springer.com, etc). When I am on the network of my lab, I can access with no problem (as long as my lab pay the expensive subscriptions).

When I am not on the lab network (let say, when I am home), my lab allows me to access each of the publishers databases by using a proxy for which I  must use one of my electronic ID they provide (www.sciencedirect.com would then be accessible through www.sciencedirect.com.ezproxy.mylab.edu/ [fake web page], I do not want to provide the real proxy] and I need to provide an ID + password).
However, I usually do not reach those database by using a bookmark or by typing the web address. It is usually through a service for online bib management (http://www.mendeley.com) or by using google scholars, or else.

The solution that I have, now, is copy the rest of the address after .com, look for the ezproxy webpage on my lab intranet, and paste this part of the address after the .edu (providing also my login info).

Therefore, my question is: how is it possible to create a rules that say, each time my browser (chrome) hit a web address, it is automatically redirected to another?

I have tried with opendns, but it only block unwanted domains. Also, my router (Linksys WRT54GL) at home does seem to support this (from the admin setup pages).

Thanks a lot.
Marc-Olivier

PS: I need to define a list of redirections, as there are many databases I need to access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to make this a little easier. But the easiest is probably to use a userscript made specifically for this purpose. Namely, the [EZProxy forwarder](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/51293) userscript.

Comment: Great! That's perfectly what I was looking for.
Thanks!